# How did I burn out this ESP8266 unit?

Tags: esp8266

ESP8266 -> FTDI -> USB Mac

I followed the wiring on this page: http://williamdurand.fr/2015/03/17/playing-with-a-esp8266-wifi-module/

[image: ESP8266 to FTDI Wiring]

I was communicating with it via Serial at 115200.  I issued a `AT+UART_DEF=9600,8,1,0,0` and a few seconds later I looked over and it was smoking.

[image: Burnt ESP8266]

I bought 2 of these.  The previous one I had wired to an Arduino Nano running through a logic level converter.  That one only returns `Exception (28)` over and over again after issuing that same command.

On both units `AT+GMR` returned:

```
AT+GMR
AT version:0.40.0.0(Aug  8 2015 14:45:58)
SDK version:1.3.0
```

Are these units too hard to use? What did I do to burn it out?

[UPDATE]

Answer given was that I fed it 5v instead of 3.3v. Obvious. I didn't think I did but I checked the output of the FTDI and sure enough it was 5.1v.  So why does the output on it say 3V3 ?  I thought that meant that it was 3.3v...

[image: 3V3 Doesn't mean 3.3v?]

Should have checked it first.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You supplied 5V to a device that only takes up to 3.6V. Heat generated by the excessive power did the rest.

Comment: I'm checkmarking you cause obviously you are correct.  But I hope to also get an answer to why 3V3 doesn't mean 3.3V?  Why not label it as VCC or +5V instead of 3V3 if it's not 3 volts?

Comment: The easy answer is that you have a defective FTDI device. It *should* be 3.3V, but clearly it is not.

Comment: Also, the FTDI device likely does not supply enough current on the 3.3V rail to run the ESP8266 module to its full potential regardless; you should get a separate 3.3V regulator and connect it to that.

Comment: I bought these but they say 150ma on the back.. http://www.amazon.com/XCSOURCE-Converter-Bi-Directional-Module-TE291/dp/B0148BLZGE?ie=UTF8&psc=1&redirect=true&ref_=oh_aui_detailpage_o02_s00

Comment: Those are level shifters, not voltage regulators.

Comment: It sort of defeats the purpose of having a small wifi unit if you need a separate power supply or regulator for each of them.  In my project I already ahve 12v going to my nano and rfid reader, a 5v regulator going to a relay and some PIR sensors. And now I need another 3.3v regulator going to this. These power requirements are annoying.

Comment: I was only using the FTDI to test and set up the wifi module. In my project it will be wired to the nano. Is there a small regulator that can take 12v and give me 5v and 3.3v out at the same time.

Comment: A few, but they won't really save you any money over a separate 3.3V LDO linear regulator. Also, consider running the Nano on 3.3V as well (although there are a few caveats about that, which you can find by searching the site).

Comment: What about this: http://www.amazon.com/Qunqi-MP1584EN-Step-Down-Adjustable-Converter/dp/B014Y3OT6Y?ie=UTF8&psc=1&redirect=true&ref_=ox_sc_sfl_title_1&smid=A12MRQC2NA7LMA

Comment: Those will work, but keep in mind that a AMS1117-3.3 or equivalent (for dropping the 5V to 3.3V) costs a very small fraction of one of those modules.

Comment: Also I found the answer and posted it here as well.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I checkmarked Ignacio's answer because it was correct.  But I wanted to leave an answer also as to HOW I supplied 5v when I thought I was supplying 3.3v.  Maybe it will help someone else.

[image: FTDI backside showing 3.3 or 5v jumpers]

The backside of this FTDI module has a jumper to select 3.3 or 5v and the default is set to 5v.  I needed to cut the default trace line connecting to 5v and solder my own jumper to switch it to 3.3v.  I should have double checked the voltage before powering it up.  New ESP01's on order.